# Autonumeric unformatOnSubmit option in Updatepanel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, autonumeric.js

I'm using the AutoNumeric.js PLUGIN inside a .aspx web page. The page represents a form with a series of textboxes that I have to save in a record. Some of these fields are numeric and are formatted using the plugin. When I save the data I read the numbers by deleting the applied format (option unformatOnSubmit: true). Unfortunately, when I save by clicking the dedicated button and postback the page loses the autoformatting.

```
<div class="tab-content">       
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upd1">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="cmdSave" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="main-card mb-3 card">
            <div class="card-body"><h5 class="card-title">Grid Rows</h5>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="position-relative form-group">
                            <label for="exampleEmail11">Codice</label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCodice" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Codice del prodotto"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="CodiceValidator" ControlToValidate="txtCodice" CssClass="is-invalid" Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="True" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>                                    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="position-relative form-group">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblProdotto" Text="Prodotto" AssociatedControlID="txtProdotto"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtProdotto" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Nome del prodotto"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="ProdottoValidator" ControlToValidate="txtProdotto" CssClass="is-invalid" Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="True" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>                                    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="position-relative form-group">
                            <label for="examplePassword11">Prodotto 2</label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtProdotto2" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Nome del prodotto 2"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="position-relative form-group">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDescrizione" Text="Descrizione" AssociatedControlID="txtDescrizione"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDescrizione" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Descrizione del prodotto"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="DescrizioneValidator" ControlToValidate="txtDescrizione" CssClass="is-invalid" Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="True" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>                                                                    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="position-relative form-group">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblBloccato" Text="Bloccato" AssociatedControlID="chkLocked"></asp:Label>  <br />                              
                            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkLocked" Enabled="false"  />                                    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="position-relative form-group">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPrezzo" Text="Prezzo" AssociatedControlID="txtPrezzo"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPrezzo" CssClass="form-control autoDecimal" placeholder="Prezzo di vendita" Text="0,00"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="position-relative form-group">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSconto" Text="Sconto" AssociatedControlID="txtSconto"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSconto" CssClass="form-control autoPercent" placeholder="Prezzo di vendita" Text="0"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="position-relative form-group">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblProvvigione" Text="Provvigione" AssociatedControlID="txtProvvigione"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtProvvigione" CssClass="form-control autoPercent2" placeholder="Provvigione sulle vendite" Text="0"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix">                                                      
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="cmdSave" Text="Salva" CssClass="mb-2 mr-2 btn btn-shadow btn-primary float-lg-right" />                                    
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="cmdCancel" CausesValidation="false" Text="Annulla" CssClass="mb-2 mr-2 btn btn-shadow btn-danger float-lg-right btn-show-swal" data-type="error" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function () {
        function pageLoad() {
            new AutoNumeric('.autoDecimal', {
                alwaysAllowDecimalCharacter: true,
                decimalCharacter: ",",
                digitGroupSeparator: ".",
                currencySymbol: "€",
                decimalPlacesShownOnFocus: 2,
                unformatOnSubmit: true
            }
            );
            new AutoNumeric('.autoPercent', {
                alwaysAllowDecimalCharacter: true,
                decimalCharacter: ",",
                digitGroupSeparator: ".",
                suffixText: "%",
                decimalPlacesShownOnFocus: 2,
                unformatOnSubmit: true
            }
            );
            new AutoNumeric('.autoPercent2', {
                alwaysAllowDecimalCharacter: true,
                decimalCharacter: ",",
                digitGroupSeparator: ".",
                suffixText: "%",
                decimalPlacesShownOnFocus: 2,
                unformatOnSubmit: true
            }
            );
        }
        });
```

I'm tried with function pageLoad()event but nothing. Textbox loser numeric autoformat.
There is a way to resolve?

Comment: Execute the plugin again after partial PostBack. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49188718/5836671

Comment: I've tried your solution but now when I click on save button have an error because value in numeric textbox was formatted and cannot save number value. Seems unformatOnSubmit: true option not work more..